# I have date slicer in my Power BI report, some days dates are not moving to show the latest date and some days they do

Tags: powerbi

I have date slicer in my Power BI report, I have cleared the selection, saved and then published. Date will move and show the latest date somedays and some days it won't show the latest date until I manually clear the selection. How do I make it show the most recent date after Everday's refresh.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to set a dynamic value as the default value for a slicer.

The best you can do is add a secondary column that will have the same value that you'll use for the default selection. For example:

| Date | Slicer Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-25 | 2023-10-25 |
| 2023-10-26 | 2023-10-26 |
| 2023-10-27 | 2023-10-27 |
| 2023-10-28 | **Today** |
| 2023-10-29 | 2023-10-29 |
| 2023-10-30 | 2023-10-30 |

In your case, I suspect you won't have continuous date like above, instead you want the latest date available to be selected. If you and your report users are okay with slicer having a default selection of "Latest" or similar, the then the above approach would work - example:

| Date | Slicer |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-25 | **Latest** |
| 2023-10-21 | 2023-10-21 |
| 2023-10-15 | 2023-10-15 |